# Sorting json with jsonArrayBuilder or java alphabetically by specific element

Tags: java, arrays, json, sorting

I am using jsonArrayBuilder and am trying to sort my json by the `text` element alphabetically. The query from the database is in the correct order, but when it goes into the jsonArrayBuilder it comes out like this:

```
[
   {
      "type":"aces",
      "text":"ACES",
      "id":"51906c47-df0e-4183-9098-8c397bf4d9a1",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"pickels",
      "text":"PICKELS",
      "id":"963c3f54-d4d4-4b89-8850-22f7ff3e7fb5",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"countries",
      "text":"COUNTRIES",
      "id":"81758026-5463-4050-8cd5-b2167cab45d5",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"agents",
      "text":"AGENTS",
      "id":"0bef956a-375d-4b06-bde9-7e0da1a1f870",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   }
]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[
   {
      "type":"aces",
      "text":"ACES",
      "id":"51906c47-df0e-4183-9098-8c397bf4d9a1",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"agents",
      "text":"AGENTS",
      "id":"0bef956a-375d-4b06-bde9-7e0da1a1f870",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"countries",
      "text":"COUNTRIES",
      "id":"81758026-5463-4050-8cd5-b2167cab45d5",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   },
   {
      "type":"pickels",
      "text":"PICKELS",
      "id":"963c3f54-d4d4-4b89-8850-22f7ff3e7fb5",
      "img":"icon-folder"
   }   
]
```

Here is how I get the data into json:

```
Collection<ListItem> listItems = Lists.newArrayList(ListItemRepository.dbReadTypes2());

        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for (ListItem listItem : listItems) {


            jsonArrayBuilder.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("type", listItem.getType().toString())
            .add("text", listItem.getType().toString().toUpperCase().replace("_", " "))
            .add("id", listItem.getId().toString())
            .add("img", "icon-folder")
            );


        }
        JsonArray listItemArray = jsonArrayBuilder.build();
```

Is there a way to sort by element in jsonArrayBuilder or how would I sort the json by the `text` element using java?

Thanks!

Comment: what library are you using for your JSON (ie, Jackson, boon, gson)? Or are you just using plain JsonArrayBuilder?

Comment: import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;